# VxWorks User Script

Tags: shell, vxworks

I am trying to create a script to be executed in VxWorks.
The script should create an output file with specific data.
I would like something like the following:

```
saveFd = open("myoutput.txt",0x102, 0777 )
oldFd = ioGlobalStdGet(1)
ioGlobalStdSet(1, saveFd)

#I would like to use three variables
#I don't know if I should use them as environment variables

putenv("MYBUSA=0x000000") 
putenv("MYBUSD=0x000000") 
putenv("DATAA=0x000000") 

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    #modify memory using my variables.
    m getenv("MYBUSA"), 4 getenv("DATAA")
    #display memory using my variables. This output should be redirected to the file.
    d getenv("MYBUSB"), 4 
    #update variable DATAA
    DATAA = DATAA + 1;
}

#recover old std output
ioGlobalStdSet(1, oldFd)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your file system, change the directory. In my case we have true flash file system from

> ->cd "/tffs0/cfg"

Create a Script:

> -> > script

Add all other relevant command here

> iosDevShow

To close the file:

> CTRL + D

Check the file if it has been created.

> ->ls

Execution of the  script, it will display in console:

> ->< script

To log all the content of script to a file use:

> < script > script.log